# The placement of a preposition in a cleft sentence

Tags: preposiciones, sintaxis

I came across this sentence while reading *Crónica de una muerte anunciada* by Gabriel García Márquez.

> **Con** lo único que no contó la familia fue **con** los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román.

While I understand what it means, I’m not completely clear why the preposition “con” is placed where it is, twice. I’m wondering if it would also be correct to say it as below.

> Lo único **con** que no contó la familia fue (or fueron?) los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román.

If both constructions are possible, what are the nuances between the two? Does one sound more literary than the other, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo sinceramente no me preocuparía todavía por este tipo de oraciones que para un estudiante de Español aún son complejas, ya que el enfoque con que has percibido la oración podría confundirte aún más.

En líneas generales, porque existen excepciones, este tipo de oraciones se llaman de "Complemento Predicativo" y tienen la característica, normalmente, de englobar dos funciones que tradicionalmente se suelen separar en;

**"Atributo y Complemento Predicativo".**

Así la oración, por ahora, debes de verla de la siguiente forma;

---

**(Con lo único que no contó la familia) fue (con los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román)**

---

El Atributo actúa únicamente con los verbos copulativos (verbos que sirven de enlace) ser, estar y parecer, y para saber cual es el atributo en una oración, tienes que hacer la pregunta ¿que? al verbo, como en el caso del objeto directo. ¿ Qué fue con lo único que no contó la familia?. En este caso, "*con los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román*"

Así de forma generalizada;

---

- "**Con lo único que no contó la familia**",  (es el complemento predicativo y una frase preposicional, "Preposición **con**" )
- **fue** (Predicado, verbo copulativo, "de enlace", Verbo Ser)
- **con los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román** ( Atributo. Sujeto. Frase también preposicional. "Preposición **con**")

P.D. No te preocupes, poco a poco.

---

**2ª PARTE**

- Oración Original

"Con lo único que no contó la familia fue con los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román". / "**Correcta**"

- Oración de Aguijonazo

"Lo único con que no contó la familia fue los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román". / **Incorrecta**

- Oración de Aguijonazo con "con"

"Lo único con que no contó la familia fue **con** los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román". / "**Correcta**"

---

**¿ Qué ha pasado ? y que debes saber aquí;**

"Con lo único que no contó" lo has convertido en " Lo único con que no contó"

Fíjate ahora,  debes conocer que en Español existen tres tipos de "con que". Estos son;

" **con que**", "con qué" y conque", son palabras homófonas, es decir, palabras que suenan de igual modo que otras, pero tienen distinto significado. El nuestro es el primero.

Los otros "conque" y con qué";

- "conque" - Es una conjunción consecutiva, introduce una consecuencia. Equivale a otras conjunciones consecutivas; *así que*, *de modo que*, *en* , "por lo tanto".
- "con qué" -  Se usa en oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas,

---

La secuencia de la oración que nos ocupa "Con lo único que no contó", está constituida por una preposición, en este caso, "**con**" y el relativo "**que**".  "Lo único **con que** no contó". En estos casos se puede intercalar un articulo, como adverbio (lo único, lo únicamente), entre la preposición "**con**" y el relativo "**que**" Con **lo único** que no contó" (con aquello que no contó, con las cosas que no contó). Sin embargo, no debes de confundirte con otros casos donde "**que**" sea una conjunción y no un relativo.

Así este "**Con que**" equivale a con el cual, con la cual, con lo cual (con aquello que no contó la familia, con las cosas que no contó la familia).

"Lo único **con que** no contó la familia, fue **con** los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román".

"Lo único **con lo cual** no contó la familia, fue **con** los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román"

"Lo único (únicamente), **con lo que** no contó la familia fue **con** los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román"

---

Viene a decir que;

"El único pensamiento que no tuvo en cuenta la familia fue que el Sr. Bayardo (poseía ó tenía) unos encantos (que eran irresistibles) o (le hacían como persona irresistible)".

Espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: ¿Qué dirías de la segunda oración? ¿Es incorrecta?

Comment: "Lo único con que no contó la familia fue los encantos irresistibles de Bayardo San Román". No, no es correcta. Arriba edite la respuesta de nuevo, en una segunda parte, 2ª PARTE, para intentar darte una explicación un poco más amplia con el objeto de que puedas comprender un poco mejor este tipo de construcciones. Eso espero.

Answer (score 1):

Your rephrasing is better than the original, no matter that it was García Márquez who wrote it. Spanish does allow *perífrasis de relativo* where the subject of the cleft sentence is a relative pronoun with an implicit antecedent (such as *lo que*) preceded by a preposition (*Con lo que no contó la familia fue con los encantos...*). Here you have to reiterate the preposition because otherwise the noun phrase after *fue* would be plural and that would jar with the singular form of *fue* (and *fueron*, if used, would in turn sound very strange next to what feels like a singular subject). If this sounds complicated and vague, it's because it is.

If the subject includes an explicit antecedent for the relative clause, however, preceding it with a preposition sounds clumsy. *Lo único con que no contó...* is fine; again, reiterating the preposition later is the way to go.

There are other syntactic contexts where such things come into play. Again, moving the preposition along with the noun phrase is more common in speech and informal registers (*Mira con la gente que se junta*), whereas more careful written prose tends to leave the preposition with the relative pronoun (*Mira la gente con la que se junta*).

Comment: Do you mean it should be *Lo único con que no contó la familia fue con los encantos irresistibles de …*, with two *con*’s even when the first *con* is placed after the noun? And I’m also wondering what prevents *Mira con la gente que se junta* from being understood as meaning *Look (at something) with the people who gather (among themselves)*.

Comment: Yes, I think it *con* should be repeated. As for *Mira con la gente que se junta*, although it's weirdly constructed, it's widely used and probably unambiguous in most reasonable contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The first excerpt would translate into "The only thing the family did not count on was the irresistible charms of Bayardo San Román." or "The only thing the family didn't count on was Bayardo San Román's irresistible charms."

The second paragraph would translate to "The only thing the family didn't count on was (or was it?) the irresistible charms of Bayardo San Román." or "The only thing that the family did not count on was (or was it?) the irresistible charms of Bayardo San Román." Here the word 'con' is being used to say the inverse of what is actually being said to prove context.

Hope this helps!